# Is it okay to buffer a differential signal using two op-amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, differential-amplifier

I want to use use an OPA1632 to amplify a differential signal and feed it into an ADC, but this draws current from the signal depending on the feedback resistors, which changes based on the gain configuration. To deal with this, I want to use an op-amp configuration like this (though with two OPA1656 instead), to buffer the input before sending it to the OPA1632.
[image: schematic]

I'm worried about the input and output offset of the op-amps messing up my signal. Is this a valid concern? If so, what should I do instead? Should I pick a specific kind of op-amp? Or use a different approach altogether?

Comment: Check out fully differential amplifier ICs.

Comment: @JonathanS. OPA1632 is fully differential. Please read my post.

Comment: Where is V1 coming from? Is it actually floating? If so, to what extent?

Comment: That *might* work. What are R1 and R2 for? They draw current from your signal source too, defeating the purpose of OA1 and OA2. By "drawing current", are you referring to input bias current? What signal amplitudes and gain are we talking about? And by "depending on feedback resistors", how does that affect source signal current?

Comment: @SimonFitch V1 would be a microphone or line input, but it would be capacitively coupled. R1 and R2 are to make sure the signal center point is 0V. I want the input impedance to be constant, and adjust the resistor network of the differential op-amp using a dual gang potentiometer. Please refer to [this application node](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa054e/sloa054e.pdf).